# Create a list of numbers from a numbers fitting certain conditions

Tags: python, list

I want to create a list `one_list` that only has the decimal of numbers that start with `1` i.e `1.3` becomes `0.3` in that list. When I run my code below however it misses out the `1.7` and only prints `0.2`. How can I get it to loop over? I only want to have the decimal part in the list, so that the contents of `one_list = 2, 7`.

```
data = [1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.7, 5.1, 6.8, 7.2, 8.3, 9.2, 3.4, 1.7]
one_list = []
while True:
    for i in data:
        integer = i // 1
        j = i % 1
        decimal = round(j, 1)

        if integer == 1:
            one_list.append(decimal)
            print(one_list)
            quit()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I remove the `while True` and the quit(), the output I get is `[0.2, 0.7]` -- which appears to match your desired output.

Comment: I see, thank you costaparas

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?
You can simply do it this way:

```
data = [1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.7, 5.1, 6.8, 7.2, 8.3, 9.2, 3.4, 1.7]
one_list = []

for i in data:
    if i - 1 >= 1 or i-1 < 0:
        continue
    one_list.append(round(i-1, 1) * 10) # Edit: Added * 10 after the question was updated.
    # one_list.append(int(round(i-1, 1) * 10)) if you want to have it as an integer or
    # one_list.append(str(int(round(i-1, 1) * 10))) if you want to have it as a string

print(one_list)
```

Comment: Thank you, really helpful, how could i make the contents of the string only (2, 7) so that the '0.' is not included?

Comment: Well this depends. What do you want it to do, if there is something like 1.345873238759. Should it return 3? Or 345873238759? Since you are rounding to 1 decimal I expect the first, then you can simply multiply it by 10, right? So it would be `one_list.append(round(i-1, 1) * 10)`. Also what do you mean by "the string"? If you want to make it into a string this needs to be done additionally.